# Exq (or equivalent) and integration tests in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've been happily writing integration tests in Elixir / Phoenix for a while, but I've recently added Exq to handle background tasks. I was just wondering how other Exq (or equivalent) are handling calls to queuing tasks in Integration tests.  I don't really want to queue these tasks at all during tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [great article about such things](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/). Basically if you have calls that you don't want to perform during tests, pass modules that make them as an argument.

```
def my_func(arg1, queue \\ Exq) do
  queue.somoething(arg1)
end
```

This way inside your code you can normally call it as before `my_func("argument")`, but in your test code you can pass a mock like this:

```
defmodule ExqMock do
  def something(arg1) do
    :return_some_static_value
  end
end

test "my_func works" do
  assert my_func("something", ExqMock) == :return_some_static_value
end
```